Visual Studio - context menu rename F2
I am using Visual Studio 2022 for editing MS Analysis Services projects ( OLAP cubes ).
If I want to rename an attribute, hierarchy or level in Dimension, the F2 shortcut key is not working. I have to right click and choose rename from context menu.
this is the context menu, where F2 shortcut is missing (https://i.sstatic.net/3RW5oflD.png)
In the previous version of Visual Studio I used (2010) the F2 key works just fine.
it's not a big issue, it's just annoying.
I try to change the keyboard shortcuts in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, but can not find the command responsible for rename.
I have found commands: Edit.Cut, Edit.Copy, Edit.Paste, Edit.Delete
which when I changed shortcut, it changed successfully.
I have found also Edit.EditCell with shortcut F2, but change of this does nothing.
thanks for your time.

I have VS 2019 and 2022 and I can confirm F2 does not let you edit attributes and stuff in dimensions. I also couldn't find a keyboard command for this in Tools, like you said. The best alternative I could come up with is hitting the menu key (on my keyboard it's next to right Ctrl) and then the up arrow a couple of times to the Rename command.
